# A proof of Serre’s converse to Hilbert’s Syzygy theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

$\def\F{\mathbb F}$ I’m reading the book “Invariant theory of finite groups” by M. Neusel, L. Smith. On page 122 they proving the following theorem:

> If $A$ is finitely generated commutative graded connected algebra over field $\F$ and global dimension is $d$, then $A =\F[z_1, \dots, z_d]$.

The proof is by induction on Krull’s dimension. At some point they choose a nonzero divisor $z \in A$, set $B=A/(z)$. For a $B$-module $M$ choose a finite free resolution
$$
0 \to F_d \to \dots \to F_1 \to F_0 \to M \to 0
$$
over $A$ and claim that
$$
0 \to F_d \otimes_{\F[z]}\F \to \dots \to F_1\otimes_{\F[z]}\F \to F_0\otimes_{\F[z]}\F \to M\otimes_{\F[z]}\F \to 0
$$
is exact. I have doubts that this is correct. Since $(-)\otimes_{\F[z]}\F \cong (-)\otimes_{A}B$ the homology of this complex are  $\mathrm{Tor}^A_i(B, M)$, but I can choose different resolution
$$
0 \to A \xrightarrow{z} A \to B \to 0
$$
and see that $\mathrm{Tor}^A_1(B, M) \cong M$. Is it a mistake in the book or am I missing something?

For example, set $A=\F[x],z=x^2$ and $M=B=A/(z)=\F[x]/(x^2)$. Then the complex
$$
0 \to \F[x] \otimes_{\F[x^2]} \F \xrightarrow{x^2\otimes 1_{\F} =0}  \F[x] \otimes_{\F[x^2]} \F \to \F[x] \otimes_{\F[x^2]} \F \to 0
$$
is not exact.

Comment: Alex: one thing to think about is the map $\mathbb k[z]\longrightarrow A$. Since $M$ is a $B$-module, it is an $A$-module and of course a $\mathbb k[z]$-module where $z$ acts by zero, i.e. $M$ is a sum of the trivial module $\mathbb k$. One would be tempted to think that pulling back the resolution you chose gives a $\mathbb k[z]$-resolution (because one *could* choose $z$ so that $A$ is free over $\mathbb k[z]$, but I do not see why this would be the case for any $z$). Have you thought about this? Have you tried the example @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez suggested?

Comment: Pedro: Yes, I worked on an example as was suggested, it is added to the post now. Even in the simplest cases the complex is not exact.